# How to filter Backbone.js Collection and Rerender App View?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, backbone.js, mongoose, singlepage

Is is a total Backbone.js noob question. I am working off of the ToDo Backbone.js example trying to build out a fairly simple single app interface. While the todo project is more about user input, this app is more about filtering the data based on the user options (click events).

I am completely new to Backbone.js and Mongoose and have been unable to find a good example of what I am trying to do. I have been able to get my api to pull the data from the MongoDB collection and drop it into the Backbone.js collection which renders it in the app. What I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do is filter that data and re-render the app view. I am trying to filter by the "type" field in the document.

Here is my script:

(I am totally aware of some major refactoring needed, I am just rapid prototyping a concept.)

```
$(function() {

    window.Job = Backbone.Model.extend({
        idAttribute: "_id",

        defaults: function() {
            return {
                attachments: false
            }
        }
    });

    window.JobsList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Job,
        url: '/api/jobs',
        leads: function() {
            return this.filter(function(job){ return job.get('type') == "Lead"; });
        }
    });

    window.Jobs = new JobsList;

    window.JobView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: "div",
        className: "item",
        template: _.template($('#item-template').html()),
        initialize: function() {
            this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
            this.model.bind('destroy', this.remove, this);
        },
        render: function() {
            $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            this.setText();
            return this;
        },
        setText: function() {
            var month=new Array();
            month[0]="Jan";
            month[1]="Feb";
            month[2]="Mar";
            month[3]="Apr";
            month[4]="May";
            month[5]="Jun";
            month[6]="Jul";
            month[7]="Aug";
            month[8]="Sep";
            month[9]="Oct";
            month[10]="Nov";
            month[11]="Dec";

            var title = this.model.get('title');
            var description = this.model.get('description');
            var datemonth = this.model.get('datem');
            var dateday = this.model.get('dated');
            var jobtype = this.model.get('type');
            var jobstatus = this.model.get('status');
            var amount = this.model.get('amount');
            var paymentstatus = this.model.get('paymentstatus')

            var type = this.$('.status .jobtype');
            var status = this.$('.status .jobstatus');

            this.$('.title a').text(title);
            this.$('.description').text(description);
            this.$('.date .month').text(month[datemonth]);
            this.$('.date .day').text(dateday);
            type.text(jobtype);
            status.text(jobstatus);

            if(amount > 0)
                this.$('.paymentamount').text(amount)

            if(paymentstatus)
                this.$('.paymentstatus').text(paymentstatus)

            if(jobstatus === 'New') {
                status.addClass('new');
            } else if (jobstatus === 'Past Due') {
                status.addClass('pastdue')
            };

            if(jobtype === 'Lead') {
                type.addClass('lead');
            } else if (jobtype === '') {
                type.addClass('');
            };
        },
        remove: function() {
            $(this.el).remove();
        },
        clear: function() {
            this.model.destroy();
        }
    });

    window.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#main"),
        events: {
            "click #leads .highlight" : "filterLeads"
        },
        initialize: function() {
            Jobs.bind('add', this.addOne, this);
            Jobs.bind('reset', this.addAll, this);
            Jobs.bind('all', this.render, this);

            Jobs.fetch();
        },
        addOne: function(job) {
            var view = new JobView({model: job});
            this.$("#activitystream").append(view.render().el);
        },
        addAll: function() {
            Jobs.each(this.addOne);
        },
        filterLeads: function() {
            // left here, this event fires but i need to figure out how to filter the activity list.
        }
    });

    window.App = new AppView;

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried [resetting](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset) the collection with the result of the "leads" filter?

Something like

```
window.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#main"),
    events: {
        "click #leads .highlight" : "filterLeads"
    },
    initialize: function() {
        Jobs.bind('add', this.addOne, this);
        Jobs.bind('reset', this.render, this); //render on reset

        Jobs.fetch(); //this triggers reset
    },
    addOne: function(job) {
        var view = new JobView({model: job});
        this.$("#activitystream").append(view.render().el);
    },
    //add a render function
    render: function() {
        this.$("#activitystream").empty(); //empty out anything thats in there

        Jobs.each(this.addOne);
    },
    filterLeads: function() {
        Jobs.reset(Jobs.leads()); //reset Jobs with only the leads
    }
});
```

Also your AppView has no 'render' method, yet you reference it here:

```
Jobs.bind('all', this.render, this);
```

Comment: Great! Thank you Ryan. The comments provided really helped me understand more how Backbone.js is working.